# Проблема редиректа и старой памяти браузера

Tags: php, кэширование, браузер, редирект

Возникла мистическая проблема, решение которой не могу найти вот уже месяц. Суть проблемы в том, что при редиректе пользователя с одной страницы на другую(при определённых условиях) в памяти браузере что-то "ломается"  и данный редирект происходит всегда, даже когда условие другое.

Например, у меня есть страница `/account` для авторизированных пользователей, при переходе на которую я всегда проверяю, авторизован ли пользователь, если нет, то делаю редирект на страницу авторизации `/login`. Вот если пользователь без авторизации переходит на страницу аккаунта система перенаправляет его на страницу авторизации, **но(!)** после авторизации пользователь вместо перехода на `/account`  опять переходит(редирект) на страницу авторизации. Важный момент, тестирование показало, что неважно какой `url` установлен при редиректе, после авторизации пользователя снова и снова перебрасывает на этот `url` т.е даже если вставляю google.ru

По стандарту, если пользователь в первую очередь проходит авторизацию и после переходит в личный кабинет, проблем нет, но если пользователь без авторизации сразу переходит на страницу личного кабинета, его перебрасывает на другую страницу(любую) и всё, в браузере что то заклинивает и далее больше не возможно перейти в личный кабинет. Данная проблема проходит только после удаления старой памяти(кеша) браузера. Я понимаю что ситуация очень нестандартная и мистическая, сам за долгие годы практики не встречал такого... но возможно кто то сталкивался с такой проблемой.

Comment: Каким образом делается редирект?

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev   Всеми возможными, и через метод самого фреймворка  и через стандартную header() и даже через JS пробовал window.location.href...  результат тот же всегда

Comment: если через header location то такого быть не должно... Точно нет ошибки в логике?

Comment: Нет, логика проста, если пользователь не авторизирован, просто редиректить на страницу входа, и всё ))  но после такого редиректа уже не пройти по ссылке личного кабинета ))) я уже психую)) как может быть такое :)

Comment: приложите весь код, наверное точно где-то ошибка)) Бывает такое, 1000 раз глянешь и не найдешь ошибку)

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev  >1000 раз глянешь и не найдешь,  да согласен, но это не тот случай )) показывать особо нечего т.к это простой редирект при определённом условии(авторизирован или нет), всю цепочку логики проверял детально,  с кодом проблем нет. Простой редирект не может вызвать "поломку" кеша браузера(историю просмотров).... тут точно что-то другое.

Comment: фантазировать будем или код посмотрим?

Comment: 1. сделайте жесткий сброс кеша браузера. 2. посмотрите в консоли браузера вкладка сеть, отметить "Preserve log" как происходит редирект. Скорее всего закешировалось, о чем будет написано "взято из кеша". А чтобы НЕ кешировалось - передавайте вместе с заголовком location и заголовки против кеширования. @teran, мы занялись некропостингом :)

Comment: @teran да, иногда фантазирование в нашем деле приносят плоды , однако, это не тот случай :) Как уже указывал в прошлых комментариях показывать особо нечего, это простое условие `if/else` т.е при переходе в личный кабинет система проверяет, если пользователь не авторизирован то его редиректим на страницу логина, если уже авториирован - проходим дальше(ничего не делаем). За последние 10 лет я написал  более 400 компонентов авторизации и личного кабинета для различных систем и такое поведение браузера замечал только пару раз. Данная проблема относится к "мифическим багам".

Comment: @teran данная проблема возникала на всех браузерах. В итоге т.к проблема не обнаружилась, пришлось колдовать и писать обходную логику без использвания редиректа. После данного первого случая, если замечаю, что на каком-то проекте выползает такая проблема, просто использую уже обкатаный алгоритм без редиректа. Таких случаев за всё время было  три раза :)

Comment: @TotalPusher не думаю, что это можно назвать "некропостингом" :)  я бы назвал "погоня за фантомным багом". Конечно же в первую очередь я очищал старую память из браузера и "вечный  редирект" проходил, однако, при переходе по ссылке в личный кабинет - порочный круг начинался заново :) Отключение кеширования  сайта также  пробовал - без результатов.